# when I type in terminal I see other characters ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I was working in an ubuntu termina remotely, form the web, so I don't have access to terminal settings.
I was looking the *git log*, and I entered ctrl+c to exit, but nothing happened, then I entered ctrl+z and I could exit the log, but then I couldn't see what I was typing, instead I was seeing other characters, form example:
If I pressed:

```
A: it shows me ^A
C: it shows me ^B
Backspace: it shows me ^H
Space: it shows me ^@
X: it shows me ^X
```

I don't know what to do, and I can't view the terminal settings becaause is a browser windows, I just see the terminal.

What Can I Do?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your control key is stuck (either physically or in software). Find all of the control (Ctrl) keys on the keyboard (there are probably two), and press them all several times to make sure that they're not stuck and they all generate key-up events.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe using an extended keyboard on the remoate pc. Use the onscreen keyboard and press the num lock. It interpreting keys that are on a keyboard without the nummbers buttons on the right side or he extended keyboard